# Delaying every element in an Observable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Say I want to subscribe to an observable, but in a way such that the Subscribe only receives elements a second after they are fired.

Is there a clean way to achieve this, other than for example

`.Subscribe(async _ => { await Task.Delay(1000); /* do something */ })`

I'm aware of `Observable.Delay()`, however it looks like it only applies to the first element in the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I think `Delay` is exactly what you are looking for. Maybe you are confusing this with `Defer`. I am sure it would have taken less time to write a quick test or LinqPad script, than it would be to create a question on Stackoverflow.